# Is audio porn haram?

Tags: halal-haram

Salam aleykoum,
i have made it so far to stop watching porn and masturbating.So my question is can we listen to porn recordings as they don t include any nudity.And there is also the fake recordings done by professionals,do they stand for the same? Thanks for all the answers(pls i need answers with proves,coran or hadith if possible)

Comment: Audio porn is the Zina of the ears...hence it's haram. Audio porn includes, possibly the woman/man moaning, groaning and breathing heavily. These sexual sound belong to the invidious who is not permissible for you. Hence haram.

Answer (score -1):

Bismillahir rahman nir rahim
Iam not a scholar. 
I trying to speak from me
Word porn itself is haraam in islam.
 If u listen audio porn its zinaah of ears, Which is forbidden in islam by ALLAH
And its sin.